# Calculating Based on Priority in Excel

Tags: excel, exception, vba

I need to calculate a value based on the conditional values of specific cells in Excel.

So I need to multiply the value in Cell A1 by the value in Cell B1 but if there is a value in Cell B2 I want to multiply by this value (only) and so on through Cell B5.

Example:

Multiply A1 by B1 or B2 or B3 or B4 on the basis of B2 taking precedence over B1 (ignore B1 value); B3 over B2 (ignore B1 & B2 values); B4 over B3 (ignore B1,B2 & B3 values) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but can you not simply use a nested If statment:

```
=IF(B2="",IF(B3="",A1*B4,A1*B3),A1*B1,A1*B2)
```

My example probably doesn't use the right cell values, but you get my point (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2,IF(ISNUMBER(B3),B3,IF(ISNUMBER(B4),B4,IF(ISNUMBER(B5),B5,"NA")))))
```

You can also use functions like ISBLANK instead of ISNUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement couples with the `<>` (not equal) operator

```
=A1*IF(B5<>"",B5,(IF(B4<>"",B4,IF(B3<>"",B3,(IF(B2<>"",B2,B1))))))
```

The nested ifs are a little tricky, but you're pretty much checking:

- If B5 is not blank, multiply by B5
- Otherwise, if B4 is not blank, multiply by B4
- Otherwise, if B3 is not blank, multiply by B3
- Otherwise, if B2 is not blank, multiply by B2
- Otherwise, multiply by B1

This assumes that B1 is guaranteed to have a value if all others do not have values